# Mathematica: Characters overlap in rotated text

Tags: text, rotation, wolfram-mathematica, special-characters

There seems to be a problem with rotating text that contains both normal and "script" characters. To illustrate this I've written a short function:

```
RotatePrint[s_String] :=
  GraphicsRow[Table[
    Graphics[Rotate[Text[Style[s, 50]], j]] // ImageCrop,
    {j, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}]]
```

`RotatePrint["Sc"]`, i.e. with two normal characters, works as expected:

[image: Two normal characters]

`RotatePrint["\[ScriptCapitalS]\[ScriptC]"]`, i.e. with two "script" characters, works just as well:

[image: Two script characters]

`RotatePrint["\[ScriptCapitalS]c"]`, i.e. with a mix of normal and script characters, however, behaves strangely:

[image: Mixed characterse]

What I find especially peculiar is that the overlap does not happen for the rotation angle Pi/2.

Thanks for your help!

Edit1: I know one can work around this by using `ImageRotate` instead of `Rotate` but this doesn't solve the problem per se.

Edit2: Since this seems to depend on the operating system and Mathematica version: I use Mathematica v8.0.0.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You should specify your operating system and your Mathematica version. In Linux-x86-64 and Mathematica 8.0.4 this does not happen.

Comment: Interesting! I've edited my post with the information.

Answer (score 1):

In *Mathematica* 7 on Windows 7 I get this to a lesser degree:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I propose this workaround:

```
rowPrint[s_String] :=
 GraphicsRow @ 
  Table[Graphics @ Text @ Rotate[Style[Row @ Characters @ s, 50], j],
   {j, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}]

rowPrint["\[ScriptCapitalS]c"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This workaround definitely looks better than the one with `ImageRotate`. I still have no idea though why this happens and why Pi/2 seems to work normally.